# how to make the elements in a gridview.builder take different hight and width

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

I'm trying to make a grid to show some pictures with different lengths and widths from an Api but when I use the  `gridview.Builder` all the items take the same layout

is there any way to change the value of `childAspectRatio` depends on the picture from the Api

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sakani/widgets/image_card.dart';
import '../constants.dart';
import '../models/picture_cat_model.dart';
import '../services/getting_pics.dart';

class ImagesBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImagesBuilder({super.key});

  @override
  State<ImagesBuilder> createState() => _ImagesBuilderState();
}
  bool isloading = true;
  List<PicCat> pictuers = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getdata();
  }

  Future<void> getdata() async {
    try {
      List<PicCat> url = await GetPictures(text: "background").getPciture();
      setState(() {
        pictuers = url;
        isloading = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      throw (e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isloading
        ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
        : pictuers.isEmpty
            ? Text("error")
            : GridView.builder(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                    maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                    childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 1,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 1),
                itemCount: pictuers.length,
                itemBuilder: (contxet, index) {
                  return ImageCard(
                    hight1: pictuers[index].length * 2,
                    image: pictuers[index].image,
                  );
                });
 
  }
}
```

Comment: You could try a package like [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)